# In EmEditor, snippets used in multiple cursors accidentally delete one character to the right

Tags: code-snippets, emeditor

When I use a snippet in combination with multiple cursors, it seems to eat up the first character to the right of every cursor while it inserts the snippet.

This happens with multiple cursors within one logical line and on consecutive lines.

It happens with and without place holders.

It never happens with macro snippets.

It never happens when I type or insert from the clipboard.

Steps to reproduce

1. Type 12345
2. Place cursors before 1, 3 and 5
3. Insert any snippet with or without placeholders, for instance 'x'.

Result:

x2x4x

The numbers 1, 3 and 5 have disappeared.

As a workaround I use macro snippets instead of normal snippets, but then I can't use place holders.

Is this a bug?

(Debug info: EmEditor Professional (64-bit), version 20.8.1 under Windows 10, up to date)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could it be that you have the editor overwrite mode switched on?

Comment: Good point, that might have explained it, but no, it fails in insert mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of this writing (v20.8), unfortunately, **EmEditor**'s **Snippets** plug-in doesn't support the multiple selection mode.

Comment: Aha. But I have several macro snippets working perfectly well in multiple selection mode, so it seems a good idea to give it a try anyway and see if it works for you.